# Bean class into a list - Java Generics - Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, generics, csv

I'm using java generics to read a CSV file and create the respective object. I'm making it generic to accept any CSV file and map it to a class.

The first line in my CSV as the class name, then I will read the remaining lines and build an object for each line.

I'm using the [CSVReader](http://code.google.com/p/jcsv/wiki/CSVReader) to help me doing it. But I get compilation errors (I marked them in the code).

Here's my method:

```
public String importFromCsvFile(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String className = reader.readLine();
    
    //Java reflection to get the Class Object.
    Class BeanClass = Class.forName(className);
    
//        Reader reader = new FileReader("persons.csv");
    ValueProcessorProvider provider = new ValueProcessorProvider();
    CSVEntryParser<BeanClass> entryParser = new AnnotationEntryParser<BeanClass>(BeanClass.class, provider); // BeanClass, cannot find symbol
    CSVReader<BeanClass> csvPersonReader = new CSVReaderBuilder<BeanClass>(reader).entryParser(entryParser).build(); // BeanClass, cannot find symbol

    List<BeanClass> beanClassList = csvPersonReader.readAll(); // BeanClass, cannot find symbol
    
    System.out.println("First line: " + className);
    
    return "";
}
```

I'm still building up my method but with this compiling errors I can not move on. Does anyone knows how to fix them?
Again, BeanClass can be any data class I've, so it has to be generic.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking to the class I think that BeanClass is no real class but you shall provide your class (bean) name to use. See http://code.google.com/p/jcsv/wiki/ValueProcessorExample. Where did you get your code from?

Comment: @LeosLiterak Yes, the BeanClass does not actually exist, it will be correspond to the class with the same name as the first line in the CSV file, that's why I use `className` and later `Class BeanClass = Class.forName(className);` Your second part I don't uderstand what you mean, could you explain it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing **static** class names, known at compile time (like `String`, or `ValueProcessorProvider`) with **variables** referencing a class, only known at runtime. It would be easier to distinguish the two if you respected the Java naming conventions: class names start with upperccase latters, and variables with lowercase letters. So the code should be

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
String className = reader.readLine();

//Java reflection to get the Class Object.
Class beanClass = Class.forName(className);

ValueProcessorProvider provider = new ValueProcessorProvider();
CSVEntryParser<beanClass> entryParser = new AnnotationEntryParser<beanClass>(beanClass.class, provider); // BeanClass, cannot find symbol
CSVReader<beanClass> csvPersonReader = new CSVReaderBuilder<beanClass>(reader).entryParser(entryParser).build(); // beanClass, cannot find symbol

List<beanClass> beanClassList = csvPersonReader.readAll(); // BeanClass, cannot find symbol

System.out.println("First line: " + className);

return "";
```

Now you can immediately see that you're using a variable, `beanClass`, in places where only literal class names, known at compile-time, can be used: what you must have between `<>` is a literal class name, not a variable, since it's used by the **compiler** to ensure type safety. I haven't checked that the following code compiles, but it should be closer than your attempt:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
String className = reader.readLine();

//Java reflection to get the Class Object.
Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(className);

ValueProcessorProvider provider = new ValueProcessorProvider();
CSVEntryParser<?> entryParser = new AnnotationEntryParser<>(beanClass, provider); 
CSVReader<?> csvPersonReader = new CSVReaderBuilder<>(reader).entryParser(entryParser).build(); 

List<?> beanClassList = csvPersonReader.readAll();

System.out.println("First line: " + className);

return "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking to the class I think that `BeanClass` is no real class. If a class does not exist, compiler cannot compile it. You shall provide your class (bean) to use. You shall implement

```
public class BeanClass { 
    @MapToColumn(column=0)
    private String firstColumn;
```

See http://code.google.com/p/jcsv/wiki/ValueProcessorExample.